# CystalReports error on WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am using CrytalReports for Visual Studio 10 (.NET 4) for WPF. Whenever I load the Window with the CrystalReportViewer, it says,

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\SAP
>   BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP
>   BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have added all the dll files/assemblies as references to the project.

[image: Project References]

Please suggest me what to do, I am really reaching my deadlines. Thanks in advance.

```
conn obj = new conn();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(obj.get_connection());

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from fee_window where dateofdeposite='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'", con);
            DataSet_daybook ds = new DataSet_daybook();

            sda.Fill(ds, "fee_window");

            ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
            report.Load(@"..\..\Report_daybook.rpt");
            report.SetDataSource(ds);
            crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
```

Added My code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the following attribute to your app.config startup element

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">

</startup>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped.
Can you please help me a little more please? Actually I am new with development for WPF, what will I need to do so that all these references also get published when I publish my project for the client?

Comment: the crystal reports problem occurs with framework 4.0 no matter wether you have a wpf, winforms, console or whatever project.

Comment: The error is gone but I get nothing on the report. I have added my code. Please consider.

Comment: That was a spelling mistake while Filling the ds. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

see this discussion.  
 http://scn.sap.com/thread/1665437 
 i hope this discussion will help you.